# Method invokation every time when viewID is changed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Since I'm working on web-application in JSF 2.1 I have to communicate with a database. We're using hibernate to do that and we have a method which is going to return the list of random customers as follows (`Customer` is an entity class):

```
List<Customer> getRandomCustomers(int count)
```

I'm not going to provide the actual definitons of the method and the entity, since I think it doesn't matter.

That method returns random `count` `Customers` from all `Customer`s stored in the database. That method is going to be used for asking for the random `count` `Customer`s and storing it into a table, called `requested_customers_per_view`.

I need to truncate the table `requested_customers_per_view` every time the `JSF` view id is changed. I have a static method

```
public class DBUtils{
   public static void truncateRequestedCustomers(){
       //Definition
   }
}
```

I mean, if we navigate to another web-page, current view's Id is changed and I need to invoke the method `DBUtils.truncateRequestedCustomers()`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you store view scoped data just in a view scoped bean?

Comment: @BalusC If I correctly got what you were trying to say I'm supposed to create a view-scoped bean for truncate's sakes and a method with something like `@PreDestroy` annotation which is going to call `DBUtils.truncateRequestedCustomers()`. Is that what you meant? But what do I do if the user is navigated from `page A` to `page B` whose managed beans are sesssion scoped? I also need to invoke `DBUtils.truncateRequestedCustomers()` in such cases.

Comment: No, I mean, why are you storing view scoped data in a DB instead of a view scoped bean? Moreover, it isn't clear if this data is supposed to be user-specific and how exactly you'd like to deal with that when an user has multiple windows/tabs open.

Comment: @BalusC Because the potential selection will probably be large enough and therefore cause `OutOfMemoryError`. Taking that into account I'm looking for a DB-oriented solution with `offset` and `limit` .

Comment: @BalusC Was I clear in what my problem is now?